# Optimizing client build - file concatenation impact on browser parsing

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, javascript-build

My application has thousands of Javascript files.
During our build process we:

1. Uglify sources (minify + concatenate)
2. Concatenate 3rd party Javascript libraries into one large file.

The result is a handful of huge .js files, each is approximately 1.5MB.
The files are ultimately cached by the browser.

The upside is reducing the client-server communication.

What is the impact of such large files on script parsing and execution by the browser? Do browsers expect such large files, or would it be better performance-wise to create smaller files?

Comment: Engines do cope pretty well with large scripts imo. Simple try it out to build more, smaller scripts.